# Best way to execute a lot of conditional expressions on a pandas dataframe to label a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, labeling

I'm looking for a good approach to label about 10k+ transactions based on different conditional expressions because it will take up to much time to do everything by hand.

For example if the name of a transaction contains "Shell" the label will be "Transport" or if the name contains "restaurant" the label will be "Food".

One possibility is to create a for loop, but that will become a mess after a while. It will look like this:

```
for i in df_transactions.index:
    if 'Shell' in df_transactions['Name'][i]:
        df_transactions['Label'][i] = 'Transport'
    if 'Restaurant' etc....
```

I also tried np.select but I need to assign one single value if one of multiple conditions is correct.

I need the labeled dataset for training a classifier with machine learning. A transaction has features like the description, an amount, account number etc.

I'm not in a position where I'm able to collect a labeled dataset by a business partner or something else.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Are all the conditions based on the value containing a specific string?

Comment: No, conditions are also based on the amount of money that's transferred and if its positive or negative for example. A positive amount is more likely to be salary. I'm also going to create conditions based on the time of the transaction. For example if a transaction took place after midnight it's probably not a transaction related to groceries.

Answer (score 1):

How many conditions are there? If it's still manageable you can use np.where:

```
df_transactions['Label'] = np.where(df_transactions['Name']=='Shell','Transport',np.where(df_transactions['Name']=='Restaurant','Food',np.where(,,np.where(,,final label))))
```

If there are many I will do something like this:

```
def load_label():

return {
    'Shell':'Transport',
    'Restaurant':'Food',
    etc
}

def labeling(name):
return LABEL[name] if name in LABEL else name

LABEL= load_label()

df_transactions['Label'] = df_transactions['Name'].map(labeling)
```

You only need to list the name and label pair and you're good to go.
Hope this helps!

Comment: still defining them. I will end up getting about 20 categories and each category could have about 20 conditions.

Comment: ahh I see, I think you need to edit the example first and we can start to work on it together again because with your current example, it looks like it only need to go through one layer of condition with many categories.